# How do you say in French “This system created by the government exploits the poorest communities.”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, constructions

The translations of “This system created by the government exploits the poorest communities.” that I have are

1. Ce system créé par le gouvernement exploite les communautés les moins riches.
2. Ce system créé par le gouvernement profite des communautés les moins riches.

I’m unsure about the part which say **les moins riches**.

Comment: "les plus démunies" would work too

Answer (score 4):

“*Profite*” is definitely wrong because it doesn't have to be detrimental. There can be mutual profit, but exploitation is one-sided. There isn't any significant difference between English and French here.

“<s>*System*</s>” should be “*système*”.

“*Les moins riches*” is not quite right: it encompasses more people than “poorest”. A straightforward translation “*les plus pauvres*” would be more accurate. However, the word *pauvre* is slightly pejorative (or maybe guilt-inducing) in late 20th/early 21st century French. Other adjectives such as *démuni* (which tends to apply to individual people) or *défavorisé* (which tends to apply to communities) are more common.

> Ce système créé par le gouvernement exploite les communautés les plus défavorisées.

Comment: ‘SO nous est hostile’ Thank you for your help! This sentence happens to be to part of a piece of literature that I’m writing and I would like some ambiguity to be present. Thus, the translation *“Ce système créé par le gouvernement profite des communautés les plus pauvres.”** is okay, right?

Comment: "Pauvre" being pejorative or guilt-inducing would be dependant on one's ideology or environment.

Answer (score 1):

You may translate `poorest communities` with:

- communautés pauvres
- collectivités pauvres
- populations pauvres
- communautés démunies
- communautés défavorisées
- communautés dans le besoin

Please double check [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/poor+communities.html) to get some examples in different context.

Answer (score 0):

Using directly Deepl:

> Ce système créé par le gouvernement exploite les communautés les plus pauvres.

If you double click above pauvres you get several suggestions; among them are démunies and défavorisées.

[image]

If one do the sane for communautés he or she will get as alternatives to communautés the words collectivités et populations.

Answer (score -1):

You can say "les moins riches", but as well, "les plus pauvres" is correct.
I see no problem in using "profite" instead of "exploite", however, there must be in the context an element which shows clearly that  can be meant by "profiter de" but the synonymous sense of "exploiter"¹ ([ref.](http://www.synonymo.fr/synonyme/exploiter)).

¹<sub>Precision made salient by [**Gilles'SOnousesthostile'**](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles-so-nous-est-hostile)</sub>

Comment: ”Profite“ is definitely wrong. ”Exploit“/“exploite” is detrimental to the poorest community. “Profite” doesn't have to be detrimental.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Qu'est-ce que vous faites de la définition suivante du TLFi : « ♦ Profiter de qqn.Exploiter abusivement la faiblesse, la gentillesse, la naïveté de quelqu'un.  » ? Comment une exploitation abusive ne serait-elle pas prejudiciable ?

Comment: “Profiter” _can_ be abusive, but the word alone does not imply abuse, so it is not adequate in this particular context. It would be adequate in some other contexts.